# Как сделать кросс-доменный AJAX POST запрос?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, post

Есть форма с инпутами. При клике на кнопку "Отправить", браузер делает пост запрос на указанный адрес и пользователь попадает на новую страницу. Это стандартный алгоритм работы `<form>`.

Задача заключается в том, чтобы заменить это дело на AJAX. Чтобы пользователь ввёл данные, нажал на кнопку и увидел сообщение об успешной отправке, но сам не перенаправлялся на другую страницу.

Проблема в том, что домен, на который делается POST запрос отличается от того, с которого идёт запрос.

Прочитал о том, что это можно сделать с помощью [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Но, как я понял, там сервер должен вернуть результат о том, разрешает ли он такой запрос или нет.

А существует ли метод решения поставленной задачи, который бы не спрашивал разрешения у сервера?

Существует ли метод фонового POST запроса на другой домен --- такой, чтобы ничего не настраивать дополнительно на сервере?

Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь приведёт пример.

#### UPDATE

Я изменил `dataType` на `jsonp`, но, как мне подсказали, получается GET, а не POST запрос.

Comment: Нельзя. Делайте на своем сервере прокладку :) Отправляйте данные с помощью ajax на свой сервер, где скрипт отправит данные на посторонний сервер и вернет вам ответ в браузер.

Comment: Если это многоразово используется повсеместно на сайте (ну например запросы к АПИ чьему-нибудь) - расширение для браузера как вариант. Оно позволяет кроссдоменные запросы делать. Правда и расширение юзер должен поставить)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это очень сложно для пользователей.

Comment: @Visman, невозможность этого мне кажется подозрительной. Я ведь могу с сервера делать запросы. Почему нельзя их делать с сайта? Разве так безопаснее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать скрытую форму, у которой `target` указывает на скрытый же `iframe`, заполнить ее из скрипта и отправить. Ограничение - ответ от сервера таким образом не получить.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Желательно, чтобы можно было получать ответ. Иначе ведь пользователь не увидит сообщение об успешной отправке.

Comment: @LEQADA с ответом это невозможно.

Comment: Не могли бы вы ещё прокомментировать обновление вопроса? Буду благодарен.

Comment: @LEQADA во-первых, JSONP всегда GET. Во-вторых, без поддержки на стороне сервера ничего "спарсить" **невозможно**. Что вам не понятно в этом слове?

Comment: Точно, GET, не заметил.

Comment: А не понятно мне неаргументированное "невозможно".

Comment: @LEQADA невозможность прочитать результат кросс-доменного запроса - это требование безопасности. Если удастся отправить запрос на другой домен и получить ответ без явного разрешения со стороны чужого сервера - это будет вектор XSS-атаки сразу на все сайты в интернете. Я думаю, такой эксплойт будет стоить пару миллионов долларов на черном рынке, если не больше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34114/discussion-between-leqada-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 3):

> там сервер должен вернуть результат о том, разрешает ли он такой запрос или нет.

Да.

> А существует ли метод решения поставленной задачи, который бы не спрашивал разрешения у сервера?

1. Отправка формы браузером. Можно настроить отправку в iframe, но доступа к его содержимому не будет. К url вроде должен быть - vk использует этот способ для авторизации, если не ошибаюсь.
2. Отправка запроса со своего сервера. Т. е. скрипт шлёт данные тебе, ты их берёшь и пересылаешь туда, куда надо, получаешь ответ и шлёшь его скрипту.

> Я ведь могу с сервера делать запросы. Почему нельзя их делать с сайта? Разве так безопаснее?

На сервере нет кук пользователя, нет никаких пользовательских данных с того сайта и т. д. Т. е. отправляемый запрос никак не связан с конкретным пользователем того сайта и не может ему навредить - поэтому да, для пользователя это безопасно.

Comment: Но если это защита пользователя, тогда зачем делать подтверждения на сервере? Зачем создавать белый лист, чтобы защитить пользователя другого сайта?

Comment: @LEQADA, сервер как бы говорит: "да, я знаю того, кто мне посылает этот запрос и позволяю ему взаимодействовать с этим функционалом". Например, у тебя собственные сайт и api на разных доменах и api говорит, да, с этого сайта обращаться можно. А вот этот я не знаю и нечего ему тут делать.

Comment: Но я ведь могу делать эти запросы прямо с сервера без какой-либо проверки. Я не понимаю, почему сервер нужно настраивать на то, чтобы он пропускал запросы с домена, но по умолчанию он пропускает запросы с другого сервера.

Comment: @LEQADA, потому что сервер не обладает информацией о другом сайте, которая есть в браузере пользователя. Вот представь форму смены пароля какого-либо сайта, например. Запросом с клиента, если пользователь залогинен, ты пароль сменить сможешь. А запросом со своего сервера?